# Url is changed automatically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working in wordpress. I have created one custom template and assign to the page.

I have created a link.Its working perfect in my localhost but not in server.

Atchually, I have created link like this :

```
http://platinumoscar.com/vendor/vendor?vendor_id=3&term_id=50
```

but its return automatically like this :

```
http://platinumoscar.com/vendor/vendor/?vendor_id=3&term_id=50
```

Here,different between both url is " **/** " after vendor.

So,what code should I have to write to resolve it?

I have changed permlink and checked but its bnot working.

Comment: There's probably a rule in your Apache configuration which is forcing a trailing slash to the URL, impossible to tell based on what information you've provided.

Comment: Provide your .htaccess file or virtual host configuration otherwise we can't tell.